# Disable Control Key

Tags: keyboard

I've already set my capslock key to act as ctrl using `setxkbmap -option ctrl:nocaps`, but now I'm trying to break myself of the habit of using the control key by disabling it.  I've tried `setxkbmap -option ctrl:none`, but that seems to have had no effect.

Briefly: I want to disable my regular left control key, so I can get used to using capslock instead.

Comment: Have you tried `-option ctrl:swapcaps`?

Comment: @Rmano I suppose that disables it as far as a ctrl key, with the added effect of punishing me for hitting it out of habit.  It's not exactly what I'm looking for, but it will do for now.

Comment: ...but then you can redefine capslock as compose and having the best of both worlds.... 